# Vim yank span given column start and end position

Tags: vim

I'm wondering in `vim`, when given a `start` and `end` column position, is there a way to yank corresponding content starts from the start position to end.

for example, given a line in vim

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

- start = 4
- end = 8

I want the yanked content is `bbbb`

The `visual mode` does finish it, but I think there may a vim command for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there may a vim command for it

The `v` to enter visual mode, the motions to extend the area, and the `y` to yank are all "vim commands".

Assuming the cursor is somewhere on the line, you can do this with visual mode:

```
5|
v8|
y
```

In command-line mode, it would look like this:

```
:call feedkeys('5|v8|y')
```

In a script, assuming the start and end are variable, it would look like this:

```
call feedkeys(start .. '|v' .. end .. '|y')
```

See `:help |` and `:help feedkeys()`.

Of note, yanking is exclusive in operator-pending mode so, if you want to yank *up to and including* column 8, you need to involve visual mode somehow, where yanking is inclusive. Explicitly, as above, or implicitly, with `5|yv8|`. It doesn't really change anything to the problem at hand but it is a feature I don't often see mentioned. See `:help forced-motion`.

Comment: much thanks, I have tried and successful, the `feedkeys` exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

We can use yank with motion `5|y9|` for this without `v`.

- `5|` go to column 5.
- `y9|` yank until column 9.

```
                                                        *y* *yank*
["x]y{motion}           Yank {motion} text [into register x].  When no
                        characters are to be yanked (e.g., "y0" in column 1),
                        this is an error when 'cpoptions' includes the 'E'
                        flag.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it, but I think `5|y9|` did it

Comment: Thx for pointing the typo, I actually mean `5|y9|`, let me correct it.